# Force a version control not to break hard links when merging/pulling from another repo?

Tags: linux, version-control, hardlink

I have a project with some part of the code that are public and other that are not.

I have the complete project versioned in my entreprise in folder E, and a specific folder P where I put the public part.
I thought it was a good idea to put hard-links in folder P of the public files in the folder E.

So that, the usual workflow should be to work on the enterprise versioned folder E, and once in a while go to folder P to commit the public files. (note that if I work 'alone', it works great)

The problem is that when I do some merging/pulling/rebasing of the files in folder E, it replaces the files -> thus changing their inode -> thus the files hard-linked in folder P do not get updated!

So my question is:
is there a version control system which authorizes an option not to change inode of files when merging/pulling/rebasing?

I work with git (or git-svn), but I would agree to switch for this convenient option.

Thanks

Louis

PS: I've seen this question ([Git and hard links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729278/git-and-hard-links)), but here I would like to take advantages of hard links to work more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use symlinks; they don't depend upon the inode, and I know they can be versioned in Subversion (and I would expect git).  Versioning hardlinks would be very difficult, since it's plausible - albeit a very bad idea - that part of your working copy could cross filesystem boundaries.

Comment: Hardlinks cannot cross filesystem boundaries. Only Softlinks can.

Comment: Yes I was doing this but if decide to move the path of internal folder, it gets messed up. (And in my case, the limit of hardlinks on a single partition is not a problem).

Comment: You can use relative symlinks, so they won't depend on the location of the tree. :)

Comment: @TurboJ - yup, that's why it's unlikely that a VCS will support hardlinks in the revisioned tree; the working copy of a repository could conceivable cross filesystem boundaries, which would make hardlinks nearly impossible to implement as hardlinks.  Because any VCS will be assuming that hardlinks aren't supported, it's unlikely that a VCS will have a checkout mode which respects hardlinks in the tree; it'll [rightly] assume that there are no unsupported files in a working copy.