# Git hook for pre-commit being invoked but hardlinks failing

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, hardlink

Please look at my answer here: [Git and hard links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729278/git-and-hard-links/9322283#9322283)

I tried to put the **same** script in `pre-commit`, but somehow the hard links are not being created.

The script is indeed executed (i.e. an `echo` inside it proves that).

I tried to run the same `ln` manually in repository root folder and same command works this way.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your accepted answer on the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731139/383402 .

The hard links are being created, and then `git` is destroying them as part of the commit.