# How to version the .git/config file?

Tags: git, version-control, config, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file like the following:

```
.*
!.gitignore
```

And I would like to version my `.git/config` file such that when I do a `git pull` my .git/config file updates automatically.

How can I do this?

I tried something like:

```
.*
!.gitignore
!.git/config
```

But this didn't work. I know if I create a link (`ln -s .git/config configurations/git/config`) I can version it, but I would like a better way to update the original one automatically.

I'm thinking of creating a hard link to it (`ln .git/config configurations/git/config configuration/git`), but it doesn't appear to be the best way. Is there a way to avoid this? Will Git work properly when versioning hard links?

**Edit: explaining why to do this**

The main motivation to do this is that I would like to version the home folder of a user of mine. I will use this versioning to help me on some kind of deploys. I'd like to keep all clones synchronized. Conflicts will appear just if I don't manage the things well, and I'll be taking care of this. Maybe I will be versioning another protected git files too.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? It sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 4):

You can't 'version' your .git/config file.  What you can do is create a .gitconfig in your working directory and commit that.  Then after a clone you perform.

```
  cat .gitconfig >> .git/config
```

Of course, **this is fraught with all sorts of potential problems**.  What if somebody edits `.gitconfig`?  You'd need to undo `.git/config` and then re-append after `git pull`.  What if `.gitconfig` changes on a different branch?  You'd need to undo `.git/config` and re-append on `git checkout <branch>`

So, I'm not recommending changing `.git/config`; but if you must, you must.

Comment: GoZoner, I agree this solution will hold, but I would like avoid this because maybe I will versioning other protected git files. But If I really can't to do this I will need to create shell script to do something similar.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by @Tuxdude it is bad information to share `.git/config` itself.

But [Git (1.7.10+) now supports config inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig/9733277#9733277)!

So, for important options you may said place them in file: `.git.config/repository.config` and in `.git/config` just place link to it like:

```
[include]
        path = ../.git.config/repository.config
```

I just add such recommendation in readme file for repo. It much easy to just copy/paste many lines and versioning important settings like regular file. It also transfer updates for all users of repo.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to version your `.git/config` file.

git doesn't let you version anything under the `.git` directory because the contents of the `.git` are local to your repo, and 2 people cloning from the same remote URL, need not have the same set of files under the `.git` directory after the clone.

For example, you might just have a single remote named `origin` while the other developer might have named the remote something like `foo` instead. Another developer might have 2 remotes named `bar` and `baz`.

The info about remotes (URLs, refspec, etc.), local branches (like upstream tracking branch, etc.), are stored in your `.git/config` file.

If you really need to override some configuration, you can edit the `.git/config` file locally or if it is an option that you could set globally use your `~/.gitconfig` or equivalent.

Comment: Tuxdude, maybe is a bad idea, but as I explain (see the edit please) on my question, I would like to version this because I would like keep this file syncronized on all clones of mine. If I will have conflits or miss configuration depends only of my managing.

Comment: I don't understand all these "No" answers... There are a lot of good reasons to version your config file. For example if you set up gitflow for a repository, why would you want to let everyone set this up locally? You'd need to create a documentation, when you could just version it...

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already excellent answers, and to actually answer the OP's question:

> I'm thinking of creating a hard link to it (`ln .git/config configurations/git/config configuration/git`), but it doesn't appear to be the best way.
>   Is there a way to avoid this?
>   Will Git work properly when versioning hard links?

No:

- hard links aren't represented in Git: see "[Git and hard links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729278/git-and-hard-links)"
- Symlinks would simply be stored as text file with the path of the linked file.