# Git tracking dotfiles (example: .zshrc)

Tags: git, bash, zsh

On my mac at the root I have my .bashrc, .aliases, .zshrc..., then in another folder down the way I have a git repository of the same dotfiles.  When I update the ones at the root, I update the git repo as well (manually).   Is there some way to 'link' the dot files that are actually implemented at the root folder to the git repo so I only have to deal with one change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually 'link' those files with `ln`. You can use either symbolic links (`-s`) or hard links. If you use a UNIX (like system) you should learn about links.

Symbolic links are essential special files that contain a path (relative or absolute) and are treated by the system as if they're the file on that path (this means that symbolic links can become broken).

Hard links (created by `ln` without the `-s` flag) are limited to a single filesystem and a hardlink is just a name for the same chunk of bytes as the original file.  Hardlinks are indistinguishable from the original file. In fact a file is just a hardlink (=name for an inode) with count 1. (The second column in the listing of `ls -l` shows you the number of hardlinks (names) that exist on the filesystem for a given file.)

I've also put my dotfiles in a repo. In my repo. I have the dotfiles in a directory named `payload` and my repo also contains a script that links the `dotfiles` in `payload` to my home directory.

The script is as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    shopt -s dotglob #make globbing catch dotfiles too
    #Use -f (force) to overwrite targets
    for file in payload/*; do ln -s .${PWD/$HOME/}/$file $HOME/; done #use string substitution
```

**Edit**
       I found that a simpler way to get the relative path in the link is to use the `-r` option to `ln`:

```
    for file in payload/*; do ln -s -r $file $HOME/; done
```

You can also create multiple links at once by using the 3rd form of `ln` (see `man ln`):

```
    ln -s -r payload/* $HOME/
```

For a hardlink version, you could do:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 shopt -s dotglob #make globbing catch dotfiles too
 ln payload/* $HOME/
```

(This hardlink version won't get broken with moves and renames, but your repo must be on the same filesystem)

(All this assumes that you've only got files (not directories) in `payload/` and that your links should have the same name as their targets.)

There are more sophisticated programs that do this in a more robust fashion.

Comment: I would use a hard link; if nothing else, that allows you to (re)move the git repo without removing the actual files.

Comment: @chepner: Good point. I didn't think of that. I've amended my answer with a a hardlink version and an explanation of hardlinks too. (Since this question is basically all about links).

Comment: Won't git break the hardlinks ? (https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/git-dotfiles-and-hardlinks/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729278/git-and-hard-links#3731139)

Answer (score 5):

What about [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)?

Just delete the file in your root, and recreate them as

```
ln -s /physical/path/to/file /symbolic/link/path
```

For example, if you have the file /git/.aliases, `ln -s /git/.aliases /root/.aliases` will create a symbolic link called `.aliases` in the `root` folder. From this point on, whichever file you modify (`/git` or `/root`) will modify the other one as well.

Have a look at [this link](https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/) for more details on symbolic links and Mac.

Please, forgive me for the random paths, I am not a Mac users.

Comment: I'm so happy that you saved me a lot of time so that I don't have to ask a new question; pointing me towards [this link](https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/), specifically [anishathalye/dotbot](https://github.com/anishathalye/dotbot#full-example) & [managing-your-dotfiles](https://www.anishathalye.com/2014/08/03/managing-your-dotfiles/)

Answer (score 4):

I usually use symbolic links for this, eg:

```
mkdir ~/.dotfiles
mv ~/.zshrc ~/.dotfiles
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc ~/.zshrc
cd ~/.dotfiles ; git init ; ...etc...
```

..so that the file that actually gets opened is the one under version control in your ~/.dotfiles directory.

Another option is use application-specific "include" features, eg:

- put your "standard" configuration in `~/.dotfiles/.zshrc`
- source that file from `~/.zshrc`:

  ```
  [ -e ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc ] && . ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc
  ```