# symlink breaking after git pull

Tags: git, vim, symlink

I keep my `.vimrc` file in a git repository since I use it on multiple computers. I don't believe there is a way to change the default location of `.vimrc`, so I keep it at `~/dotfile/.vimrc`. I created a symbolic link between these with `ln ~/dotfiles/.vimrc ~/.vimrc`, which I then confirmed worked with `ls -i ~/.vimrc` which shows `12345 /Users/TheStrangeQuark/.vimrc` and then `ls -i ~/dotfiles/vimrc` which shows `12345 /Users/TheStrangeQuark/dotfiles/.vimrc`.

Now, I pull the latest version of my `.vimrc` while in `~/dotfiles`. Now, the symbolic link is broken, which I can confirm by seeing different inode numbers from `ls -i` for the two files. I also can see that `~/.vimrc` is not the updated version from my `git pull`.

Is there a way to make it so my `git pull` won't break this symbolic link?

I am running MacOS Majave if that helps.

Comment: That's not a symbolic link. Try `ln -s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Git and hard links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731139/6309)", hard links cannot be represented in git, at least not without third party tools, or a [`post-merge` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9322283/6309).

This differs from soft link (`ln -s`), which are [stored as a file pointing to the destination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9322283/6309).

See also "[What is the difference between a hard link and a symbolic link?](https://blog.usejournal.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link-8c0493041b62)".