# How to store soft/hard linked files in git repository?

Tags: git

We've previously used Accurev as version control for our project now we moved to GIT. In Accurev, we can able to create files as links(soft/hard). But in GIT, if we push the hard/soft link files, its committed as physical file only. We are using solaris for our project. Will Git support these kind of link file type?
Is there anything we can do with git-hooks?

If any one knows, Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git and hard links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729278/git-and-hard-links). The essence: git can not handle hard links, and it handles softlinks without any problem. It might have a problem to handle symlinks on Windows, but it is a windows limitation and not a git one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links)

Comment: Thanks. Have already gone through that. but i couldn't add comment there so created a new post. as mentioned in that post-merge is not called when running git pull. created a simple post-merge inside git/hooks with echo Hello. Created post-checkout and run git checkout, post-checkout is executed.